# Python: Referring to any created object with __init__

Tags: python, object, init, refer

Am building a program in which i use the constructor method in a class.
My method looks like this:

```
class Myclass:
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        Myclass.population +=1
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        popFile = open('pop.txt', 'wt')
        popFile.write('population = ' + str(int(Myclass.population)))
        print('blablabla')
        print('again blablabla')
        popFile.close()
        pliada = (var1, var2, var3)
        outFile = open('prog.txt', 'at')
        outFile.write(str(pliada) + '\n')
        outFile.close()
```

My problem is that in the above

```
outFile.write(str(pliada) + '\n')
```

I want to save apart from the tuple, the objects name! What else should I add inside the write() func?

For example when I run the program, i type:

```
First = Myclass('firstvar','secondvar','thirdvar')
```

and when i use

```
print(First)
```

it only prints the above tuple. When I open prog.txt, again its only the tuple there.
How can I refer to each object's name (am constructing) so that instead of saving ('firstvar','secondvar',thirdvar') my program will save First ('firstvar','secondvar',thirdvar'), where First is the var I entered to the program?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. Your program is badly designed. _Technically_ you can, but if you do that I don't think anybody would appreciate your technical competence.

Comment: I see. Am totally noob in all these... I just learned the open function and I thought I could do something like this...

Comment: your var `pliada` doen't exists

Comment: sry just fixed this...

Comment: @midkin it is a bad idea to treat "variable names" as data within a python script (see e.g. [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)). Why not have a dictionary `{'First': ('firstvar', 'secondvar', 'thirdvar')}`? You could save this as text or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it.

Comment: Yeah you're right! That's what Yann suggested too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At object creation time, an object does not have a name. In fact, having a name is fundamentally not how Python's type system functions, although modules, types and functions are created with `__name__` attributes.

```
In [12]: compile("First = Myclass('firstvar','secondvar','thirdvar')", "sample", "single")
Out[12]: <code object <module> at 0xf5fde458, file "sample", line 1>

In [14]: dis.dis(Out[12])
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (Myclass)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('firstvar')
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('secondvar')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('thirdvar')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             15 STORE_NAME               1 (First)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that the name `First` has not appeared at all until after `Myclass` is called using `CALL_FUNCTION`. The object returned by Myclass therefore has no clue about the existence of First (indeed, it doesn't exist until after the assignment STORE_NAME). The only way it could be found would be some insane black magic by tracing back the stack to find at what point the caller called the constructor and then interpret the future execution to find the name; and it is not guaranteed to even exist, let alone be as easy to understand as this sample.

What your object has, however, is an identity. Identities are not universally unique, but while the object exists, no other object has the same identity within the same process. You could find that identity using `id(self)`, and the default stringification also includes it: `str(f)` produces things like `<__main__.Foo instance at 0xf603f46c>` (names of the module and class, while the instance id is printed in hexadecimal).

Once the name does exist, it is not a property of your object, but an entry in the namespace of the executed code (might be a module or a function call). It can equally be assigned into any other similar entries, such as attributes of other objects, and none of them are particularly authoritative; each points to the same unnamed object.

If you do want to name your objects, the easiest way is to simply pass a name to the creation, as with all your varN attributes.

Comment: So if I create a program using the __init__ function and save text to a file and then I want to remove some text but I only remember the objects name that I used, I have no option, right?
If for example i use First = Myclass('firstvar','secondvar','thirdvar'), and then I want to remove this line of text but I don't remember anything, there in no way to use something like: del First?

Comment: I'm having difficulty following this question. `__init__` is a method, called at instance initialization (as part of an object creation in an already running program). `del` removes names, which might lead to object deletion if no other references exist. I think you need to sort out the differences between stored data (such as text files), process state (a process is in principle a running instance of a program, and its state contains things like name tables and objects), and program source.

Comment: Well my purpose on this program is to create people with 3 characteristics. For example:
Yann = PeopleClass('Tall', 'Thin', 33)
and so on... When created with __init__ method, print('self who is {} and {}, aged {} just joined our village!'.format(self.one, self.two, self.three)) and save "Yann, tall, thin, 33" in a file..
When Yann leaves the village, if Yann in open('village.txt', 'rt').read():
outFile = open('file.txt', 'wt')
and do something to remove the whole like of Yann...

Comment: So essentially create a text file that reflects the state of a collection of objects within your running program. The simplest way to do this is probably to make the collection itself update the file, for instance by subclassing a dictionary to make it rewrite the file for every setitem or delitem. The reason to rewrite the whole file is because most systems don't actually have a remove line operation.

Comment: Using the file to store state across separate program executions is a different matter; you'd need a format that could be used to restore the object model. Python provides a module named `shelve` to do that, but then the file is not human readable text.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you wrote:

> Well my purpose on this program is to create people with 3 characteristics. For example: Yann = PeopleClass('Tall', 'Thin', 33)

If you want the name "Yann" to be a property of the person, you should include it as an attribute of the object (and probably pass it as an argument to the constructor), rather than using it as a variable name. Variable names should not be data!

Not all objects are bound to a variable with a simple name. For instance, if you have a list of people, you could access them through identifiers like `people_list[0]` and `people_list[1]`. Those wouldn't be too attractive to print out though! Similarly, a single object may be bound multiple times in variables with different names. If after you ran the code in your above comment, you did `John = Yann`, the same PersonClass instance could be reached through the variables `Yann` and `John`, and your code would have a very hard time knowing which was being used at any given moment.

So, rather than:

```
Yann = Person("Tall", "Thin", 33)
```

Do:

```
my_person = Person("Yann", "Tall", "Thin", 33)
```

(And of course, update the class definition to accept and store the name being passed in.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could do it is to pass the name of object as another parameter to **init** method.

First = MyClass("First", "first_var", "second_var", "third_var")

==============

self points to the object that has created it

self + str(pliada) + '\n'

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Myclass' and 'str'

Comment: Also tried outFile.write(str(self)+str(pliada) + '\n'), but i won't save each object's name...
I don't want to save the Class's name but the just created by __init__function object's name...